# Apache Rewriterule with or without slashes on end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following Apache RewriteRule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but it only works when the user types in a URL without an ending /

eg: `www.mydomain.com/contact`

This does not work: `www.mydomain.com/contact/`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because your regex is wrong which makes `$1` as `contact/` when you enter `www.domain.com/contact/`.

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```